# How to share office webapp addin in orgnization using the same file for multiple office tenant/orgnization

Tags: office365, office365-apps

I have created Excel template by inserting the my newly created office addIn in excel file, when I copy the same excel file to another tenants one drive location, add-in is not displayed in excel, I have had copied the same manifest file to other organization/tenant/admin catalog, but from the error it looks like excel file tries to load the add-in by searching it in 1st tenants catalog. I get error as shown in below image. Is there any way to get around this issue
In below image, excel file was created by tenant pulasetty.onmicrosoft.com by placing manifest in https://pulasetty.sharepoint.com, I am trying to access this excel file from new tenant/org bhiogade.onmicrosoft.com and I had same manifest in https://bhiogade.sharepoint.com

[image]

the error i see when tried to load

[image]

If I have office **addin from office store** I found that creating file in one tenant and access same file from other tenant show office addin without issue.  How to test this in development envinormnet, in development I can’t have my addins added in office store yet.

Answer (score 1):

the concept of sideloading can be used in this case, instead of adding the manifest file in catalog, user can upload the manifest in insert addin dialog once, and then after that every time a template excel is copied to users one drive location and is opened it is opened properly with addin. following link explains how to load manifest file.

https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/docs/testing/sideload-office-add-ins-for-testing.md

this technique can be used for testing..

i production excel file loaded with office addin from store, can be shared with multiple tenant by copying it to their one drive location and it would open the addin without any issue.